# Use single datePicker to validate dates on multiple UITextFields (i.e. fromDate < toDate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am using a single `UIDatePicker` on multiple `UITextFields`. When a `UITextField` is tapped, it calls the `UIDatePicker` and updates the text as the picker is scrolled. This all works fine, though now I would like to do some validation. My `UITextFields` are "Employed From" & "Employed To", I need to check that the `"From"` field is always less than the `"To"` field (i.e. a person can't be employed `FROM` 1995, `TO` 1990).

Here is my code which sets a default date and sets the input view for each UITextField:

```
- (void)datePickerTextField {
    // Open date picker when textfield is tapped
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    // Set default date
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [components setDay:1];
    [components setMonth:1];
    [components setYear:1980];
    NSDate *defaultDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [datePicker setDate:defaultDate];

    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(updateDateTextField:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Set input for each textfield
    [self.empFrom1 setInputView:datePicker];
    [self.empTo1 setInputView:datePicker];
    // ... more fields
    [self.empFrom10 setInputView:datePicker];
    [self.empTo10 setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
- (void)updateDateTextField:(UIDatePicker *) datePicker {
    // Format date
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    UIAlertView *validDate = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                       message:@"Please check dates"
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Check which textfield is active and set date
    if ([self.empFrom1 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empFrom1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate];

        NSString *empFrom = self.empFrom1.text;
        NSString *lastFour = [empFrom substringFromIndex:empFrom.length - 4];
        _from = @([lastFour integerValue]);
        NSLog(@"FROM: %@", _from);
    }
    else if ([self.empTo1 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empTo1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate];

        NSString *empTo = self.empTo1.text;
        NSString *lastFour = [empTo substringFromIndex:empTo.length - 4];
        _to = @([lastFour integerValue]);
        NSLog(@"TO: %@", _to);

        if (_from > _to) {
            [validDate show];
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the above snippet isn't working, as the `NGLog` clearly outputs the correct `integer`, yet the alert still displays even if the `FROM` is less than `TO`.

[image: Attempted solution]

I have searched around and can't seem to find a working solution when re-using a single `UIDatePicker` for multiple `UITextFields`. Is this even possible? Or would I have to create a new `UIDatePicker` for each field? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)updateDateTextField:(UIDatePicker *) datePicker { 

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; 
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]; 

    UIAlertView *validDate = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check dates" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 

    // Check which textfield is active and set date 
    if ([self.empFrom1 isFirstResponder]) {   
        self.empFrom1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate]; 
        self.dateFrom = datePicker.date; 
    } else if ([self.empTo1 isFirstResponder]) { 
        self.empTo1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate]; 
        self.dateTo = datePicker.date; 

        if( [self.dateFrom timeIntervalSinceDate:self.dateTo] > 0 ) { 
            [validDate show]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Add 2 NSDate-properties to your class, for example dateFrom & dateTo

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. I don't necessarily need to check if the date is valid (i.e. not in the future) as I have already accounted for that in the `datePickerTextField` method (correct me if I'm wrong). I just need to check that `FROM` is always less than `TO`. Please see my updated post which shows another attempted solution - am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you add the following line inside your if-check where you display the alert? NSLog(@"%@ < %@", _to, _from); And please add the console-output :)

Comment: The output from your NSLog is: `NGLS[45133:60b] FROM: 1985
 NGLS[45133:60b] TO: 1988
 NGLS[45133:60b] TO: 1990
 NGLS[45133:60b] 1990 < 1985` - then it doesn't drop back into that test after scrolling the `TO` field. No matter what date I set in the `TO` field, the alert doesn't show again. Strange, do I need to reset the input or something? Thanks.

Comment: It is highly irritating that 1990 is smaller than 1985 as it clearly isnt. Are you sure the theck is the correct way round? Because either the NSLog or  the if-check is the wrong way round, because I dont think the computer would make calculation-mistakes like this.

Comment: I have just reversed the if-statement `(_from < _to)` and `NSLog(@"%@ < %@", _from, _to)`, and it still drops into the test when scrolling the `TO` field: `FROM: 1982
 TO: 1986
 1982 < 1986
 TO: 1964
 1982 < 1964`. I don't understand why this code isn't working. As you said, it's a simple calculation of ints which shouldn't be a problem whatsoever. Just to clarify, I have declared `_to` and `_from` as `NSNumbers` in my .h file. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm why dont you save the NSDate instead of a number? Then you could also compare days/months instead of just the year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62817/discussion-between-tmob-and-rosshump).